# Convergence in Measure on the Unit Circle

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f\in L^{\infty}(S^1)$ where $S^1$ is equipped with the Haar measure. Then since this measure is finite, thus $f\in L^{2}(S^1)$
and thus $\exists$ a sequence of trigonometric polynomials 
$s_n=\sum\limits_{k=-n}^nc_ne^{ik\theta}$ such that $s_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^{2}(S^1)$. I now want to conclude that $s_ng$ converges to 
$fg$ in $L^{2}(S^1)$ $\forall$ $g\in L^{2}(S^1)$. I suppose that the proof will be quite easy, but I somehow cannot lay my hands on the proof.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Something seems strange ... Even considering that the measure is finite,  if  $f \in L^{2}(S^1)$ and $g \in L^{2}(S^1)$, $fg$ may not be in $L^{2}(S^1)$.

Comment: Yes,I also found this quite strange.